# android - how to smooth bitmap after scaling

Tags: android, bitmap

Using the tutorial "[loading large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)", I scaled a large bitmap and used it in an `ImageView`. But, after down sampling the bitmap, it's quality dramatically decreases. In `Actionscript`, the `Bitmap` object has `smoothing` property to solve this problem. Is there any alternative in android (java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`BitmapDrawble`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) sending it your `Bitmap`. `BitmapDrawble` has methods like `setFilterBitmap(boolean filter)` and `setAntiAlias(boolean aa)` that may suit your needs.

`ImageView` can easily receive `BitmapDrawbles` via `setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)`.